# why the continer box is not fitting

Tags: flutter, dart

why the continer box is not fitting
[image]

```
 Container(

                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    height: 150.h,
                    width: 270.w,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
                      color: AppColors.myCardColor,
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/Card.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  );
```

Comment: Try adding `alignment: Alignment.center` to Container.

Comment: doesn't work @DholaHardik

Comment: try setting the image as part of the decoration instead
      
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
            "assets/images/Card.png",
          ),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
        color: AppColors.myCardColor,
      ),

Comment: try changing fit to BoxFit.fill first

Comment: Add your full code,

Answer (score 0):

use this package it may help you

[carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

it shows the images the same way you want

[image]